# Переименование окна другой программы SendMessege

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Нужно, чтобы программа переименовывала окно второй программы. Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                                                              
#include <wchar.h>                                                               

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND Find = FindWindow(NULL, L"lab10.exe");
    SendMessage(Find, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Заголовок-1");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [FindWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww) вторым аргументом принимает название окна. А вы, вероятнее всего, передаете не то, что нужно.

Comment: И чему же равно значение `Find` в ваших экспериментах? Почему вы не привели эту информацию в тексте вопроса?